# How many calls would you expect to ASP.Net SQL Server session state SP ASPStateTempSessions

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, session-state

I am investigating a performance issue a .NET Framework 4.7.2 ASP.NET MVC web application.

Using SQL Server Profiler I can see there are  hundreds of calls to a stored procedure in SQL Server database called `TempGetStateItemExclusive3`.

There appear to be 4 per second with the third and fourth calls consistently happening at the same millisecond.

A quick google suggests this stored procedure is related to ASP.NET session state.

There is only 1 row in `ASPStateTempSessions`, which an old post I found suggested might be an issue if old sessions weren't being cleared out.

While go away to teach myself about that, can anyone advise as to

- if they would expect this many calls to this stored procedure so frequently
- if not, suggest anything to focus on which could be the cause?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you know how session state works, you can take the persistent store out of the equation by changing the mode to out of proc or in process settings.